# Isomorphic Measurable Spaces definition

Tags: measure-theory, inverse

In *Probability and Stochastics*, (Cinlar), isomorphic measurable spaces are defined as follows:

[image]

So we have a bijection $f$. But then it's emphasized that we have a  *functional inverse* $\hat{f}$. Why is this distinction necessary? Is $\hat{f}$ not also a bijection? Are there other inverse functions (or I guess, are there multiple bijective maps from $(F, \mathcal{F})$ to $(E, \mathcal{E})$)?

I know isomorphism means that there's a bijection that preserves structure (e.g., for vector spaces, linearity is preserved), it's not clear to me what structure exactly is being preserved (since both spaces are already measurable)?

Comment: Do you have the defintion of a function being measurable? I think you are confusing a measurable space with a measurable function here. The important point is, that f preseverses the structure of the measurable sets

Comment: You are right that there's only one inverse function, so there would be nothing wrong with dropping "functional". Perhaps the author wanted to distinguish from $1/f$. Your title has a mistake, which it seems is related to your misunderstanding - this paragraph is not about isomorphisms of measure spaces, but isomorphisms of measur*able* spaces. The structure to preserve is "which sets are measurable". Do you agree that $(E, \mathcal P(E))$ and $(E, \{\emptyset, E\})$ don't usually have the same structure?

Comment: I suspect that "functional inverse" is being used/emphasized here to avoid confusion with pre-images/inverse images. In the setting of measure spaces, the symbol $g^{-1}(A)$ is used very often because pre-images are often considered. I expect it's just to avoid confusion.

Comment: Piggy-backing on Izaak's comment, since $f$ is a bijection, it induces a bijection $\Phi_f:2^E\to 2^F$ between the power sets $2^E,2^F$ of $E,F$ via $\Phi_f(A)=\{f(x):x\in A\}$. Then $f$ is an isomorphism between measure spaces iff (it is bijective and) $\Phi_f|_{\mathcal{E}}$ is a bijection of $\mathcal{E}$ with $\mathcal{F}$. In other words, $A\subset E$ is $\mathcal{E}$-measurable iff $f(A)$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable.

Comment: I believe that Cinlar only wanted to emphasize that $\hat{f}$ is not the pseudo-inverse of any sort that exists as [quantile function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function#General_distribution_function) for a general CDF.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Edited the title. that example is helpful, thanks :)

Comment: It is required that both $f$ and $\hat{f}$ are measurable.  Bijective and measurable in one direction is not enough.  The situation is similar to define a homeomorphism of topological spaces: both $f$ and $\hat{f}$ must be continuous.